# Querying aggregate columns in a SQL Server SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have a SQL Server query which runs just fine -- until I add a computed column to the SELECT statement.  Then I get an odd SQL Server error.

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT
    outmail_.MessageID_, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),outmail_.Created_,120) AS 'Issue', 
    lyrReportSummaryData.mailed, 
    lyrReportSummaryData.successes, 
    COUNT(*) AS 'opens',
    COUNT(DISTINCT clicktracking_.MemberID_) AS 'unique_opens', 
    convert(decimal(3,1),((convert(float,[unique_opens]))/[successes]) * 100) AS 'Rate'
FROM 
    outmail_ 
RIGHT JOIN 
    clicktracking_ ON clicktracking_.MessageID_ = outmail_.MessageID_
RIGHT JOIN 
    lyrReportSummaryData ON lyrReportSummaryData.id = clicktracking_.MessageID_ 
GROUP BY  
    outmail_.MessageID_, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), outmail_.Created_,120), 
    lyrReportSummaryData.mailed, lyrReportSummaryData.successes
```

The problem is the line beginning with the `convert(decimal  ...`  When it is included, I get the following error:

> Error 8120: Column 'lyrReportSummaryData.unique_opens' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm not sure how to resolve the error since I don't know how to use it in a `GROUP BY` clause (and it doesn't seem that I should need to do so).

Any suggestions for how to proceed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure someone with better DBA skills than me can point out a more efficient way of doing this, but...

If you perform the bulk of your query as an sub-query, you can then do the calculations on the result of your sub-query:

```
 SELECT 
    MessageID_, 
    Issue, 
    mailed, 
    successes, 
    opens, 
    unique_opens, 
    convert(decimal(3,1),((convert(float,[unique_opens]))/[successes]) * 100) AS 'Rate'

 FROM 
 (SELECT
      outmail_.MessageID_, 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),outmail_.Created_,120) AS 'Issue', 
      lyrReportSummaryData.mailed, 
      lyrReportSummaryData.successes, 
      COUNT(*) AS 'opens',
      COUNT(DISTINCT clicktracking_.MemberID_) AS 'unique_opens'


    FROM outmail_ 
    RIGHT JOIN clicktracking_ ON clicktracking_.MessageID_ = outmail_.MessageID_
    RIGHT JOIN lyrReportSummaryData ON lyrReportSummaryData.id = clicktracking_.MessageID_ 

    GROUP BY  outmail_.MessageID_, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), outmail_.Created_,120), lyrReportSummaryData.mailed, lyrReportSummaryData.successes
   ) subquery /* was 'g' */
```

Effectively what this does is runs the grouping, and then based on that, does the calculation afterwards.

Subqueries must be given an alias (in this instance 'subquery') - even if you don't use that alias name.

Comment: Seems like that should work, but it's throwing a syntax error:  Error 102: Incorrect syntax near ')'  Any ideas what that's about?  Thanks.

Comment: I missed the 'g' at the very end of your query.  Once I added that, everything worked.  I'm obviously a MSSQL newbie; what does the 'g' indicate?

Comment: The g is an alias for the sub query. You can give tables aliases as well, they work just the same. For example `select s.staffid, s.name, p.payrate, p.startdate  from staff s join payrate p on s.staffid = p.staffid`  - and yes, this means you can join or put additional restrictions on a sub query.